# How can I attach the bottom to the top of Nintendo 3DS XL?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, hardware

I took a Nintendo 3DS XL apart to replace the bottom middle portion of the shell because the hinge broke.

I took the bottom and top apart to change this piece.  Where they connect is a small hinge on the left side of the bottom half through which 3 ribbon cables and 1 other cable go through and the right side which has the power light and hinge.

I have put the cables through the left side and attached that side, but cannot figure out how to get the hinge on the right connected.

I watched some tutorials and this part is kind of glossed over.  It appears that they have somehow slid part of the hinge into a slot on the top half and then pushed it back once the halves are lined up, however I am unable to push the hinge inside to top half far enough to do anything like this.

Is there a trick to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to post pictures later, but the hinge must be twisted so that it is straight.

The tutorials seem to assume that it already is because they show someone taking a working 3DS XL apart and then putting it back together.  When they do this, the unit is closed, so the hinge is in the correct orientation.

If you are fixing one that broke, your hinge may be set to the position it is when the system is open, and the hinge won't push into the top portion in this position.  You will need to use pliers to twist both sides of the hinge until it is straight.  Then it will fit inside the top portion so that you can attach the two parts.